# How to put columns in a solution?

Tags: math-mode

I want to separate the solution into two columns. What can I possibly add to this?

```
\sol{}
```

Comment: I am asked to solve for the f_x(x,y) and f_y(x,y). I want to show the solution for the former on the left and the latter on the right. How to do that?

Comment: There are several ways.  You could use paracol (outside math mode), which will even allow you to align separate equations.  I take it the internal structures of the solutions are not the same, otherwise you could use align with `x&=a & y&=b\ \` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that `\sol` isn't the name of a LaTeX macro but, rather, a shorthand expression for a longer, possibly multi-row, derivation of some mathematical result involving the partial derivative(s) of a function `f(x,y)`.

Assuming that the solution for `f_x(x,y)` fits in an otherwise invisible box whose width is less than `0.5\textwidth`, I can think of (at least) two ways of proceeding. First, a single `align*` environment with two columns. Second, two separate `minipage` environments of width `0.5\textwidth`, placed side by side, the left-hand one for `f_x(x,y)` and the right-hand one for `f_y(x,y)`. While the second method may seem easier to implement at first blush, it requires extra care -- below, in the form of two `\smash[b]` wrappers -- to assure that the rows line up across the two minipages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env. and '\smash[b]' macro
    
\begin{document}
\noindent
Let $f(x,y)=(3x+2y)^2$. Then, by a twofold application of the chain rule,
\begin{align*}
 f_x(x,y) 
   &= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x+2y)^2 &
 f_y(x,y)
   &= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x+2y)^2\\
     &= 2(3x+2y)\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x+2y) &
     &= 2(3x+2y)\tfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x+2y) \\
       &= 2(3x+2y)\cdot 3 &
       &= 2(3x+2y)\cdot 2 \\
         &= 18x+12y\,. &
         &= 12x+ 8y\,.
\end{align*}

\noindent
Alternatively,\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 f_x(x,y) 
   &= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x+2y)^2 \\
   &= 2(3x+2y)\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x+2y)\\
   &= 2(3x+2y)\cdot 3 \\
   &= 18x+12y\,.
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 f_y(x,y) 
   &= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial\smash[b]{y}}(3x+2y)^2 \\
   &= 2(3x+2y)\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\smash[b]{y}}(3x+2y)\\
   &= 2(3x+2y)\cdot 2 \\
   &= 12x+ 8y\,.
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```